# Cannot find why ngRoute is not loaded: Module 'ngRoute' is not available

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

guys.

I know this error is pretty old, I already found many answers about this issue, but I still could not find the fix.

I`m getting the following error message:

angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <title>My test Website</title>
        <meta name="author" content="me">
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="ContentController">
        <ul class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</li>
            <li><a href="#nothing"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Portfolio</li>
            <li><a href="#nothing"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Articles</li>
            <li><a href="#nothing"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i>Books</li>
        <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>About Me</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Nothing here {{ 1 + 2}}</p>

        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </body>


</html>
```

App.js

```
var websiteApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);


    websiteApp.config(  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: '/views/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });

    websiteApp.controller('ContentController', function ($scope) {
        console.log("content controller loaded");
    });

    websiteApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
        console.log("main loaded");
    });

    websiteApp.controller('AboutController', function ($scope) {
        console.log("about loaded");
    });
```

I know I might be missing a really simple detail, but I have double checked all the answers of related issues on stack overflow and I can`t find out how to fix this one.

I believe preparing a fiddle won`t help you, because the problem seems to be related to the reference to angular-route.

Also, I have already disabled caching on my browser.

Could you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a spelling mistake at this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
```

it should not br **scr** but **src**

Answer (score 0):

You should update your script tag to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Also, there is a better and recommended way to declare your configuration in the `config` file. This technique makes sure your code stays consistent with `Angular`'s guidelines.

```
websiteApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: '/views/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        }])
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps.